# How can I hide the medicine when the Quantity is equal to 0?

Tags: mysql

I want to show the medicine in the table if the `tbl_medicine.status` is Active and `Quantity` is not equal to 0? My problem is when the value of the `Quantity` is equal to 0 it's still showing on the table. And this error comes out `#1052 - Column 'Quantity' in where clause is ambiguous` when I don't put this `tbl_medicine` beside the `Quantity`. How can I hide the medicine when the `Quantity` is equal to 0? Here's my query

```
SELECT tbl_medicine.medicine_id, tbl_medicine.supplier_medicine_id, 
 tbl_medicine.quantity, tbl_medicine.status, tbl_medicine.barangay_id, 
 (IFNULL(tbl_medicine.quantity - SUM(tbl_received_order_details.quantity),0)) AS 
 Quantity, tbl_medicine.barangay_id AS Barangay 
FROM 
 tbl_medicine 
INNER JOIN 
 tbl_received_order_details ON tbl_received_order_details.supplier_medicine_id 
 = tbl_medicine.supplier_medicine_id 
WHERE 
 (tbl_medicine.status = 'Active' AND tbl_medicine.Quantity != 0) AND 
 DATE(NOW()) > tbl_received_order_details.expiration_date AND barangay_id = 1 
ORDER BY 
 medicine_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Quantity` is a derived column (it's a result when you subtract two other columns). It doesn't exist on any of the tables, therefore you can't use it in a `WHERE` clause.

The fix you are after is adding a `HAVING Quantity > 0` clause.